# Running embedded R code in Oracle raise error

Tags: r, plsql, oracle12c

I am a newbie in Oracle R embedded execution.
well, I have following code registered as

```
BEGIN
  sys.rqScriptDrop('TSFORECAST');
  SYS.RQSCRIPTCREATE('TSFORECAST',
    'function(dat){
      require(ORE)
      require(forecast)
      myts <- ts(dat,frequency=12)
      model <- auto.arima(myts)
      fmodel <- forecast(model)
      fm = data.frame(fmodel$mean, fmodel$upper,fmodel$lower)
      names(fm) <- c("mean","l80","l95","u80","u95")
      return(fm)
      }'
  );
END;
```

as I execute the function for the first time with this code:

```
select *
from table(
rqTableEval(
  cursor(select balance from tmp_30),
  cursor(select 1 as "ore.connect" from dual),
  'select 1 mean, 1 l80, 1 l95, 1 u80, 1 u95 from dual',
  'TSFORECAST'
  )
)
```

it generates the results I expected. But after that it will never produce any result but instead it raises this error:

```
ORA-20000: RQuery error
Error in (function ()  : 
  unused arguments (width = 480, bg = "white", type = "raster")
ORA-06512: at "RQSYS.RQTABLEEVALIMPL", line 112
ORA-06512: at "RQSYS.RQTABLEEVALIMPL", line 109
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.
```

I have searched this error but could not find anything helpful. Can anyone help me with this error?